# Проблема с кодировкой ORACLE

Tags: oracle

Есть SQL Developer, в нем все таблицы отображаются нормально(то-есть русские символы в таблицах). Но когда я пытаюсь вывести таблицу через php на сайт - вместо русских символов получаю "?????????". Подскажите пожалуйста что сделать что бы на сайте таблицы отображались корректно?

Comment: вы покажите код? дело в том, что без кода, достаточно трудно подсказать.

Comment: Выполните `select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where parameter in ('NLS_CHARACTERSET','NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET')` в SQL Developer и через PHP на сайте, сравните результаты.